# Get Yule Walker estimates from autocorrelations

Tags: time-series, arima, simulation, autocorrelation, autoregressive

I'm looking to be able to estimate parameters of an AR(2) time series using the sample autocovariances. I have:

```
gamma_hat_0 = 130
gamma_hat_1 = 111
gamma_hat_2 = 60
gamma_hat_3 = 9
```

and I need to estimate the parameters:

```
phi_1
phi_2
sigma_sq
```

My first thought was to simulate the time series and extract the parameters estimates that way, but I can't find a way of simulating an AR(2) process using just the autocovariances. Is there a way? Am I approaching this incorrectly, would a mathematical approach be easier? If so, is there any resource that people know of to show how I can estimate the model params from the autocovariances?

Comment: The title mentions autocorrelations but the body mentions autocovariances; which is it? The Yule-Walker equations are a pretty straightforward way of doing this, so since you seem to be aware of them, what exactly is the issue?

Comment: @ChrisHaug Thanks for your reply - there is a mistake in the title. I have the autocovariances, and I need to estimate the parameters using these. Everywhere I look I can see how to estimate them from autocorrelations, but I can't seem to figure out how to get there from the autocovariances